# How to send one window to the other application

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

Send and retrieve Serialized XAML between two  apps and re-create the Control (or XAML Object).
I want to know how to Serialize XAML
My code:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           String s = XamlWriter.Save(this);
             Console.WriteLine(s);
            //serialize the window

            try　　
          　 {　　　　 
                int port=8900;　
                string host="211.87.227.183";　
                IPAddress ip=IPAddress.Parse(host);
                IPEndPoint ipe=new IPEndPoint(ip,port);　　　
                Socket c=new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
                Console.WriteLine("Conneting...");　
                c.Connect(ipe);　
                string sendStr=s+'@';　
                byte[]bs=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendStr);　　
                Console.WriteLine("SendMessage");　　
                c.Send(bs,bs.Length,0);　　　
                string recvStr = "";　　　　 
                byte[]recvBytes=new byte[2024];　　　
                int bytes;　　　　
                bytes=c.Receive(recvBytes,recvBytes.Length,0);　　　
                recvStr+=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBytes,0,bytes);　　　
                  Console.WriteLine("ClientGetMessage:{0}",recvStr);　　　　
                  c.Close();　
       　  　 }　　　
                   catch(ArgumentNullException e1)　
　　          {
　     Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException:{0}",e1);　　　
                      }　　　 
                       catch(SocketException e2)
  　　      　 {　　　　 
                               Console.WriteLine("SocketException:{0}",e2);　　　
                         }　　　
                         Console.WriteLine("PressEntertoExit");　　　 Console.ReadLine();
        //using socket to send the string
       }
```

code of the host:

```
  StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);
         XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);//receive string from socket
         Window win = new Window();
         win = (Window)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);// error:It cannot cast to the window type
         Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(win);           

    }
```

The following is the string i get from the xaml:

```
    <MainWindow Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="Manual".... Name="MainGrid"><av:Grid.LayoutTransform><av:ScaleTransform </MainWindow>
```

Comment: +1 for idea :) But what about binding ? Do both applications have the same underlying ModelView ?

Comment: I want to send the window in my computor to the screen of another computer.I cannot deserialize the window.